# Partitioning points with values so that each partition has equal sum total

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing

Let's say I have a 2D plane populated with points. Each point has some value. I would like to divide up the points in k partitions so that each partition has an approximately equal sum total. The partitioning divide should be a made up of straight lines.

It seems that k-mean clustering is close to the mark, but it does not take the values into account. Maybe I can penalize each cluster for having a high sum and then recalculate the assignment step after this. But I am not sure how to do this penalty so that the sum is close to equal. Maybe k-means is not a good algorithm to modify. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use k-means as an initialisation step, to get a first grouping of the points, and then move the borders to equalise regions

Comment: Straight lines? Or straight line segments?